# Differences between mod_fastcgi and mod_proxy_fcgi

Tags: apache-2.4, php-fpm, fastcgi

I have searched for an answer but cannot seem to find anything substantial related to this question.

Should one use `mod_proxy_fcgi` or `mod_fastcgi` with `php-fpm` on Apache2.4?

Are there any differences in terms of security and performance?
Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`mod_proxy_fcgi`, which is newly available in Apache 2.4, is just for this type of use case. The [Apache wiki entry for PHP-FPM](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HTTPD/PHP-FPM) has some good guidance to get started.

The [`mod_proxy_fcgi` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html) also includes specific examples for setting up PHP-FPM and the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php) also has helpful information.

On the other hand, `mod_fastcgi` is notoriously difficult to set up and a memory hog. Additionally, `mod_fcgi` doesn’t support spawned CGI servers. Because PHP-FPM is managed by itself, not by Apache, `mod_fcgi` isn’t the best choice.

Comment: This explains why nothing was working when I attempted to set up mod_proxy_fcgi, I have Apache2.4.7 and a habit of using unix sockets. :) Any comments on performance? I know mod_fastcgi uses memory but is it faster?

Comment: speed should not be an issue, although using sockets is probably more efficient; probably more important to be able to spawn PHP-FPM processes

Comment: So I will be sticking to mod_fastcgi because it seems the more logical choice. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Yeah I prefer using sockets for efficiency.

Comment: I think the right answer is `mod_proxy_fcgi` - the spawning capability is important for efficiency

Comment: If I use mod_proxy_fcgi I cannot use unix sockets, unless I upgrade my apache. The problem is that this will not happen on Ubuntu 14.04 unless I use a PPA right?

Comment: That is right. You will have to balance spawning against sockets, until 16.04. On the other hand, even with using a "port" you will get dramatic speed improvements with the 14.04 set up; test them both (`mod_proxy_fcgi` no sockets vs `mod_fastcgi` no spawning) and report back in a comment - I am sure we would all like to see the "data"

Comment: Is `mod_fastcgi` still notoriously difficult to set up and a memory hog if you are using `FastCGIExternalServer` with php-fpm? Does `mod_proxy_fcgi` have any benefits over this setup?

Comment: 4 years later .. still waiting on "report back in a comment - I am sure we would all like to see the 'data' ".

Comment: mod_proxy_fcgi's benefit, esp. in Debian systems, is that you can simply install the php-fpm package and run the sudo a2enconf commands that it tells you to run, and you're done, no extra Apache configuration is required.